# CFWheels - How can I use the errorMessagesFor after a redirect?

Tags: model-view-controller, coldfusion, railo, cfwheels, bluedragon

Is there any way to use the #errorMessagesFor()# method after a redirect in the controller?

Reason I ask is that I want the form to stay on the same page.

I have a URL like:

/link/submit/

With a form that posts to:

/link/linksubmit/

But I want it recirected back to /link/submit/.

I can do this, and it works, but then the #errorMessagesFor()# no longer works in my view.

I don't want to use a "flash" message for this because I want specific error messages to be shown for the fields on the form. Is there perhaps a way to pass the validation errors to a flash message?

Thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wheels isn't really designed for the pattern that you're suggesting. What you need to do is render the form page in your `linksubmit` action after validation fails.

This is the pattern to follow:

```
<cffunction name="linksubmit">
    <cfscript>
        link = model("link").new(params.link);

        if (link.save()) {
            redirectTo(route="someRoute", success="The link was created successfully.");
        }
        else {
            flashInsert(error="There was an error saving the link. Please review the errors below and try again.");
            renderPage(action="submit");
        }
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```